# Load a css file on webpack run

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2

I'd like to always load a css file

in my angular2 bundle (I'm using my own boiler plate NOT ng-cli)

like ng-cli does with style.css.

I don't want to load it for instance using an import

in main.ts or app.component.ts but by webpack.

What's the way ?

Any hints ?

Thanks in advance

### Sort of (it doesn't work)

```
{
   test: require.resolve(helpers.root('src','styles.css')),
   loader: 'imports-loader'
}
```

### Tried with this (it doesn't work)

```
entry: {
   'styles': './src/styles.scss',
   'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
   'main':      './src/main.ts'
},
new CommonsChunkPlugin({
   name: 'styles',
   chunks: ['styles']
})
```

### 2) Attempt

**main-style.loader.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function(source) {
    this.cacheable();
    const callback = this.async();
    const stylesPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'../src','styles.scss');
    this.addDependency(stylesPath);
    fs.readFile(stylesPath, "utf-8", function(err, header) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        console.log(header,source);
        callback(null, header + "\n" + source);
    });
};
```

**webpack**

```
{
   use: [
      'raw-loader',
      'sass-loader',
      'postcss-loader',
      helpers.root('config','main-style.loader.js')
   ]
 }
```

But I've got

```
Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed: Unknown word (7:1)
    5 | }
    6 | 
  > 7 | 
      | ^
    8 | 
    9 | 
  :
  Syntax Error: Unknown word (7:1)
    5 | }
    6 | 
  > 7 | 
      | ^
```

### 3) Attempt thanks a ton to @bebraw

The hint come from
https://github.com/peerigon/extract-loader
(You should have a postcss.config.js)

it workish the only drawback is .my class become like

.QZ4j2umHjjSjpjIMYOm2C

```
const mainCss = [
  'postcss-loader',
  'css-loader',
  helpers.root('src','styles.css')
];
mainCss.unshift('style-loader');
entry: {
  'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
  'main':      './src/main.ts',
  'mainstyles': mainCss.join('!')
},
```

### WATCH OUT

The css loader modules flag
should be set to false and
it works :D

Comment: If you are using angular-cli, then in angular-cli.json check for `"styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ]` and add your extra css file to this `styles` array. Like `"styles": [
        "styles.scss", "custom.css"
      ]`

Comment: I just wrote this "in my angular2 bundle (I'm using my own boiler plate)"

Comment: As per this: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter#external-stylesheets we have option to import it. Please do let us know if you figure out how to include it with webpack. :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I'd like to have the styles.scss in my bundle without "import '../styles/styles.scss'" (in src/app/app.module.ts)  like ng-cli do - so I try hard to write a custom loader with no luck by now :(

Comment: With your cue even I'm trying to figure out a webpack loading solution. But in vain. All experiments have failed. I will update if succeeded. Please to update if you succeed.

Comment: I hope so :) but I see it very hard :(

Comment: @VinitSarvade I've update my post first step :)